# How to 'clear' a cell while a editor is active?

Tags: grid, extjs4, editor, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I have a grid with a CellEditor plugin. Now I have a renderer for boolean which inserts a html tag with a image class. Now it happends the Editor does not cover this image. The defined field get just placed in a layer above. Is there a way to clear/cover the cell content when using a CellEditor.

Please notew that this not happends with primitve types like when the renderer just output a number or string.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/B3fW3/3/)

column-model

```
{
    header:'Required',
    dataIndex:'Required',
    renderer: function(v){return v?'<div class="icon-class"></div>':''},
    editor: {
        xtype: 'checkbox',
        value: false,
        inputValue: 'true',
        uncheckedValue: 'false'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A code example would be helpful, in the meantime though, try setting a css z-index on your html tag with a value of  -1 through 1 and see if that helps.

Comment: How would I do that? I added a example

Comment: What is the result you want to see, do you want the (+) icon to be visible at all times?